# Show alert depending on value of input in JS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an input with id `pc-verify`:

```
<%= form.text_field :address2, :id => 'pc-verify' , :class => 'required' %>
```

If the user fills in the value "28028", and without submiting the form, I want to show an alert.

How can I achieve this?

I've tried:

```
  <script> 
    if ($("#pc-verify").value == "28028") {
          alert("hey");
    };
  </script>
```

### Edit

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".pc-verify").on('change', function(e){
            if ($(".pc-verify").value == "28028") {
                  alert("hey");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without submitting the form you can use the change event of the input

```
$("#pc-verify").on('change', function(e){
    if ($("#pc-verify").val() == "28028") {
          alert("hey");
    }
});
```

This way when the user types the value and leaves the field, the value check will happen. You could also do it on keyup which would check on every key released in that input

```
$("#pc-verify").on('keyup', function(e){
    if ($("#pc-verify").val() == "28028") {
          alert("hey");
    }
});
```

You have your script inside a script tag but not inside the document ready handler, in jquery you must do this so that the script is executed only when the page finishes loading

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#pc-verify").on('keyup', function(e){
        if ($("#pc-verify").val() == "28028") {
              alert("hey");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Gibson on your edit you are using the class selector .pc-verify but the field has an id #pc-verify. Change your selectors to #pc-verify like on my example and let us know if it works

Comment: Sorry i'm finally using classes instead of ids, and it wont work with id either!

Comment: Ok worked! The problem was I was using value() instead of val(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and then use the `value` property if you want *native* javascript

```
if (document.getElementById("pc-verify").value == "28028") {
          alert("hey");
    }
```

**Or**, if you are using `jQuery`, use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
if ($("#pc-verify").val() == "28028") {
              alert("hey");
        }
```

Finally, you can wrap them in a [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    if ($("#pc-verify").val() == "28028") {
         alert("hey");
         return false;//to prevent the form from being submitted
    }
});
```

Comment: I marked Juank answer as best because It didn't need to submit the form, but yours works great also. Thanks